# disassociate a device I don't have anymore from market account?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove device(s) from My Market Account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8276/how-to-remove-devices-from-my-market-account)

How can I disassociate a device I don't have anymore from my Google Market account? This is a device that I used to have working but it's not anymore, so I don't want it to show up in my Google Market account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this. It has been [suggested](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/android-market/8seNuKof2jM) [numerous](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/technical-help/jdXzG8G2CqA) [times](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/android-market/uHN7J0Bo734) on Google's forums, but has never been acted on.

The best you can do for now is "hide" devices that you don't want to appear in the menus. You do this by logging into the Android Market website, then going to your account settings by clicking the gear icon and selecting "My Market Account" and then the "Settings" tab. On this page you should see a list of devices associated with your account. If you click the "Edit" button to the right of a device's name you can then select "Hidden in menus".