# Unregister device in Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove device(s) from My Market Account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8276/how-to-remove-devices-from-my-market-account)

I've two devices showing in my Google Play Account, probably because of some old ROM. I want to remove the old entry. I can't install apps to my phone through the website anymore...

[image: The same devices!]

I can't see any Option in the Google Play Settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this.