# How can older devices be deleted from Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

AirDroid keeps reminding me I haven't updated one of my devices but I don't own it anymore. I can't find the option to remove the older smartphone from Google Play either! Unchecking "show in menus" didn't work.

Comment: Still not possible, AFAIK: [How to remove device(s) from My Market Account?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8276/how-to-remove-devices-from-my-market-account)

Comment: That was answered in 2011. How do we know It's still up to date?

Comment: Try. The only place were you *could* do so is on the Dashboard in the web. I didn't see they've added an option there to remove a device, but I might just have missed it.